# Webview Database Error

Tags: android, database, webview

I have the following problem.
I implemented a Webview in my Android App, the Webview should load a HTML File that uses JavaScript. This is the code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                System.out.println(errorCode);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(getFilesDir());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
            webView.clearView();
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        }
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+getFilesDir()+File.separator+"0", line, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

First everythings works fine, but if the WebView run for a view Hours, i will get the following Error and the app get terminated shortly after it:

```
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp: sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27862 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/com.example.rebmann.prozessueberwachungkonfignr2/databases/webview.db
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp: sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27862 - "" errno=2 path=/NotificationPermissions.db, db=/data/data/com.example.rebmann.prozessueberwachungkonfignr2/databases/webview.db
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 380K, 14% free 7767K/8967K, paused 5ms+2ms
Application terminated.
```

For that reason i trying to use the `onReceivedError` method to catch that Error, but the method never gets called. (I know it's the old version of the method, but since I use a old Version of Android on my Phone that's fine).

Does anyone have any idea why i get this Error and how i can handle it.

**EDIT:**

I upgraded my Android to the newest supported version (4.1.2) and now i'm getting a more detailed error log, maybe that helps:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/FileSyetmQuota.db) - 
D/WebKit: ERROR: 
D/WebKit: SQLite database failed to load from /FileSyetmQuota.db
          Cause - unable to open database file
D/WebKit: external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - 
D/WebKit: ERROR: 
D/WebKit: SQLite database failed to load from /NotificationPermissions.db
          Cause - unable to open database file
D/WebKit: external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
```

Comment: Paste full logs from logcat when apps get terminated